# No such file or directory - Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am running the following with Amazon Sagemaker

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1', 
                        # Set up AWS credentials 
                        aws_access_key_id=key_id, 
                         aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)


s3.create_bucket(Bucket = 'gid-datacamp')

s3.upload_file(Filename = r'C:\Users\Filippo\Desktop\WineQT.csv' , Bucket = 'gid-datacamp', Key = 'WineQT.csv')
```

but despite the directory being the correct one I get the following error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Filippo\Desktop\WineQT.csv'

I also tried to directly import the file using pd.read_csv() and I got the same error.

Is there something I don't know about how boto3 and my local machine interact?

thanks!

Comment: You run the python code on SageMaker notebook, and you want to access your files on your local computer?

Comment: yes - I am trying to upload a csv file in my bucket gid-datacamp, is there something incorrect with it?

Comment: You have to run the python code on your local machine, not SM.

Comment: is there a way to do it from SM rather than on my python? So that I do not have to manually upload the files on the S3 bucket

Comment: No, unless you setup ssh or ftp server (or similar) on you local host which is accessible from the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python script should run on your **local machine**, not SageMaker (SM).

SM does not have access to your local computer, unless you setup some kind of connection between SM and your home/work computer. Once you have that you can access the files through server (ssh or ftp) running on your local computer.

Comment: thanks Marcin - just one clarification then - what is s3.upload_file() used for then? what am I uploading things from?

Comment: @FilippoSebastio It uploads a file to S3. But you have to run the code on your local machine, as the file is there.